# Flask - Display results of code to the webpage

Tags: python, flask

I asked a similar question yesterday I think but I guess that I didn't really explain what was my problem. I have a program that retrieves some data from a request. Everything is fine if I run it from the Terminal, everything good and now I want to know how can I display those results to a webpage. It's just a plain thing, nothing fancy. A blank webpage with the text-results there. This is the script:

```
for key in r['playerstats']['stats']:
    if key['name'] == "total_kills":
        print("Total kills: " + str(key['value']))

    elif key['name'] == "total_deaths":
        print("Total deaths: " + str(key['value']))
```

The process is simple: there's a form, the user puts their name on it and then below the code does the requests and everything and the results are displayed.

That's a part of the code that does the process, let's say I want to display the results of the code above. How can I do it on flask? Do I have to replace the `print-s` for variable names? Do I have to paste the code on the flask script?

The output of that is (something like):

```
Total kills: (number)
Total deaths: (number)
```

But I don't know how can I take that from just a terminal to the webpage; that's my concern and I hope someone can help me. If I need to elaborate more my question, please let me now :)

P.S. I read part of the Flask and Jinja2 documentation but to be honest I didn't quite get parts of it and hopefully with an answer from here I'll be more on track.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to get the basic flask tutorials and examples working, by that point you'll either have an idea how to modify them to show what you want or will have some code you can ask for help with. But you're probably not going to get familiar with flask by asking questions here.

Comment: use `return` to send text/HTML/template to browser

Answer (score 2):

./main.py

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html', kills=10, deaths=5)

app.run()
```

./templates/index.html

```
Total kills: ({{ kills }})
<br/>
Total deaths: ({{ deaths }})
```